# How to get form control validation errors in template in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form which changes its validation based on some value from the dropdown. If college A is selected then min percentage required in 60, if college B is selected then min percentage drops down to 55.
Although I have figured out a way to get the min error in the template in so that I didn't have to hard code the percentage value in my template. Although I am not sure if this is the correct way or not.

```
<div formGroupName="marks">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Semester 1</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <input autocomplete="off"
             #sem1
             type="text"
             min="0"
             max="99"
             maxlength="1"
             maxlength="2"
             class="form-control"
             id="email"
             placeholder="Sem 1 (%)"
             (keypress)="onlyNumberKey($event)"
             formControlName="sem1">
      <span *ngIf="registrationForm.controls['marks'].controls['sem1'].hasError('required') &&
                   registrationForm.controls['marks'].controls['sem1'].touched"
                   class="text-danger">
        Sem 1 percentage required
      </span>
      <span *ngIf="registrationForm.controls['marks'].controls['sem1'].hasError('min') ||
                   registrationForm.controls['marks'].controls['sem1'].hasError('max') ||
                   registrationForm.controls['marks'].controls['sem1'].hasError('minlength')||
                   registrationForm.controls['marks'].controls['sem1'].hasError('maxlength') &&
                   registrationForm.controls['marks'].controls['sem1'].touched"
                   class="text-danger">
        Percenatge must be {{ registrationForm.get('marks.sem1')._errors.min.min }}  and above.
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
registrationForm = new FormGroup({
  college: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required, dropDrownValidator
  ]),
  marks: new FormGroup({
    sem1: new FormControl('',
      [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.min(60),
        Validators.max(99),
        Validators.minLength(1),
        Validators.maxLength(2)
      ]
    )
  })
});
```

Answer (score 7):

To achieve what you want, you have to *watch* the changes in your `college` *control*.

You can do this using `(change)` in **template**:

```
<select formControlName="college" (change)="handleChange($event.target.value)">
  ...
</select>
```

or even using `valueChanges` in **component**:

```
this.registrationForm.get('college').valueChanges.subscribe(college => this.handleChange(college));
```

And in your `function`, based on what *college* user selects, you can set the min value to your validator using [**`AbstractControl#setValidators`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValidators) + [**`AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity) (to apply ), as below:

```
handleChange(selectedCollege: string): void {
  const min = selectedCollege === 'CollegeA' ? 60 : 55;
  const control = this.registrationForm.get('marks.sem1');
  control.setValidators([Validators.required, customMin(min)]);
  control.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

---

**Tips:**

1 - Since, you're using model-driven forms you shouldn't put validations in your HTML, keep it clean and put everything in component.

2 - You can use `FormBuilder` in order to simplify the construction of `form` (see the demo at the bottom).

3 - You should never access private properties like this:

```
{{ registrationForm.get('marks.sem1')._errors.min.min }}
```

Just use `errors` instead of `_errors` if you need to.

4 - You can simplify even more your markup:

Instead of:

```
<span *ngIf="registrationForm.controls['marks'].controls['sem1'].hasError('required') &&
             registrationForm.controls['marks'].controls['sem1'].touched" 
             class="text-danger">
  Sem 1 percentage required
</span>
<span *ngIf="registrationForm.controls['marks'].controls['sem1'].hasError('min') ||
             registrationForm.controls['marks'].controls['sem1'].hasError('max') ||
             registrationForm.controls['marks'].controls['sem1'].hasError('minlength')||
             registrationForm.controls['marks'].controls['sem1'].hasError('maxlength') &&
             registrationForm.controls['marks'].controls['sem1'].touched"
             class="text-danger">
  Percenatge must be {{ registrationForm.get('marks.sem1')._errors.min.min }}  and above.
</span>
```

You can have:

```
<div class="text-danger" *ngIf="registrationForm.get('marks.sem1').touched">
  <span *ngIf="registrationForm.hasError('required', 'marks.sem1')">
    Sem 1 percentage required
  </span>
  <span *ngIf="registrationForm.getError('customMin', 'marks.sem1') as error">
    Percentage must be greater than or equal to {{ error.min }}.
  </span>
</div>
```

---

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-akyve7)